# Can you use matrices to solve for gravitational potential energies

Tags: matrices, python, transpose

I was wondering whether its possible to use matrices to calculate the gravitational potential energy of a system. I know it's possible to calculate the acceleration due to gravity on a system by matrices but was wondering if it was possible to implement it with the potential. For gravity, the implementation is as follows, if the position is split into x, y, and z. Then the transpose of those respective elements subtracted by the original matrix finds the distances between all the points. Then if dx, dy and dz are squared

$$ 
x = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where x in this case holds all the positions of the respective objects. The numbers indicating different objects. Then
$$
dx = x.T - x = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3\\
\end{pmatrix}
- \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & x_1-x_2 & x_1-x_3\\
x_2-x_1 & 0 & x_2-x_3 \\
x_3-x_1 & x_3-x_2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The same is true for the y and z axis like the x. The following matrix stores 1/r^3 for all particle pairwise particle separations and raises it to the correct power.

$$ inverse = (dx^2 + dx^2 + dz^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}
$$
therefore leading to

ax = G * (dx * inv_r3)(objects_mass) - sorry didn't know how to nicely display this.

The main question is now is this type of matrix manipulation relevant for Gravitational potential. The equation for which is

$$
U(r) = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r}
$$
This varies from the one of gravity but with the main difference of multiplying by the other mass. So I was wondering if something like the following would be possible.
$$
m = \begin{pmatrix}
m_1\\
m_2\\
m_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where m contains all the masses
$$
m_m = (m)  (m.T)
$$
Thereby getting a multiplication of all the masses to each other and then the following

$$
(G\cdot m_m)*(dx^2 + dx^2 + dz^2)^{-1}
$$

Is something like this mathematically correct and if not can something similar be done? Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a novel way of subtracting matrices. By the usual rules, you can only subtract one matrix from another if they have the same number of rows and the same number of columns.

Comment: sorry what do you mean it's a novel way. Is it bad? is there a better way to find the distances between objects using matrices?

Comment: I mean, the usual way, if $A$ has $n$ rows and $m$ columns, then $A-B$ is only defined if $B$ also has $n$ rows and $m$ columns, and then the answer has $n$ rows and $m$ columns, and you get the entries of the answer by subtracting each entry of $B$ from the corresponding entry of $A$. You can't (by the usual definition) subtract a three-row, one-column matrix from a one-row, three-column matrix. So you are using a different definition of matrix subtraction from the definition used in math.

Comment: Oh ok. I knew it wasn’t the traditional method but as the result was nice I thought there would be some exception if you subtracted a matrix from its inverse. Does that mean it’s not possible to calculate the potential from matriculated then?

Comment: Inverse? The usual word is *transpose*. I don't know about calculating the potential. Let's hope someone else comes along.

Comment: Sorry you’re right don’t know why I called it the inverse